# Check for 'file not found' or parse errors

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I have got a weired error message from the compiler, when I try to run the app:

```
com/example/RequestAccess/view/JobProfileCart.view.xml could not be loaded from ./view/JobProfileCart.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason: Error: Invalid XML: <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="com.example.RequestAccess.controller.JobProfileCart" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page id="detail" title="{i18n>jobProfileCart}" backgroundDesign="Standard" floatingFooter="true"
        class="sapUiContentPadding sapUiResponsivePadding--header sapUiResponsivePadding--subHeader sapUiResponsivePadding--content sapUiResponsivePadding--footer">
        <headerContent>
```

I do not know, why it complains that the file can not be found:

[image]

although it exists.

The content of the `JobProfileCart` should also be correct:

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="com.example.RequestAccess.controller.JobProfileCart" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page id="detail" title="{i18n>jobProfileCart}" backgroundDesign="Standard" floatingFooter="true"
        class="sapUiContentPadding sapUiResponsivePadding--header sapUiResponsivePadding--subHeader sapUiResponsivePadding--content sapUiResponsivePadding--footer">
        <headerContent>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://user-edit" type="Transparent" press="onPressEdit" ariaLabelledBy="editButtonLabel"/>
        </headerContent>
        <content>
            <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormDisplay480" minWidth="1024" maxContainerCols="2" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="2"
                labelSpanM="2" emptySpanL="0" emptySpanM="0" columnsL="2" columnsM="2">
                <f:content>
                    <Label text="{i18n>id}"/>
                    <Text text="{User>/Id}"/>
                    <Label text="{i18n>name}"/>
                    <Text text="{User>/Surname} {User>/Firstname}"/>
                    <Label text="{i18n>email}"/>
                    <Text text="{User>/Email}"/>
                </f:content>
                <f:layoutData>
                    <FlexItemData shrinkFactor="0" backgroundDesign="Solid" styleClass="sapContrastPlus"/>
                </f:layoutData>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </content>
        <footer>
            <OverflowToolbar>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                <Button type="Accept" enabled="{SendStatus>/enable}" text="Send" press="handleJobProfileSend"/>
            </OverflowToolbar>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be the resource roots reference on the `index.html` or wherever you inject your Component. I don't think it's a problem in the file itself. What is the ID of your app in the manifest.json? Is it referenced as `com.example.RequestAccess` everywhere?

Comment: Even if the WebIDE doesn't show errors the XML can be invalid. You can validate XML with external Tools, just search for `XML validator`. It would have told you that `The Prefix "f" For Element "f:SimpleForm" Is Not Bound., Line '10', Column '88'.`

Comment: So much for SAP Web IDE - the _go-to IDE for UI5 apps_. I'm glad they finally gave up working on it.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I have not found out how to easily extend standard apps without the WebIDE, so to me at least it has it's (limited) purpose.

Comment: @Marc Sorry, it was one of those useless rants I sometimes express. I'm definitely grateful for Web IDE. But it was [not easy for internal devs either to maintain the IDE](https://youtu.be/Rj35nCxw_9U). Happy they could find a solution with Eclipse Theia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no definition for namespace `f` in the header. Try adding `xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"`.

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

If parse error happens for xml view,copy the xml view code into another xml file and open it in edge browser.edge will show which line the error happpened.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).